# Read a file with a specific encoding in C?

Tags: c, encoding

I've a file that was written on windows with encoding WINDOWS-1256, and I need to write a C program that reads bytes from this file and write them back to a new file with UTF-8 encoding.

How to read a file with a specific encoding in C ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than text mode and binary mode, there is no way to directly read specific encodings with C with standard API.

You would open the file as binary and read it in.  Then you can use a library like [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) to do the encoding / decoding of specific formats.

Comment: in C, I can define a unicode string using wchar_t, right? What if I want to define a string with other encoding, say gbk?